# Wacom Intuos (CTL-490) not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: tablet, wacom, graphics-tablet

I've been trying to get a CTL-490 to work on an Asus laptop... to no avail.

I've already compiled the drivers by following both the official instructions and [these](http://matthewwittering.com/blog/ubuntu-tips/how-to-install-a-wacom-intuos-ctl-480-tablet-on-ubuntu.html) too.

I managed to solve the missing packages (xorg-server, xproto, etc.) errors I was getting by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-dev libxext-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxi-dev libudev-dev
```

Everything seems to have worked fine, but when I try to load the modules I get this error on one of them:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wacom_w8001': Exec format error
```

I'm a very inexperienced Linux user and any help I could get to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem (Wacom CTL-490, Ubuntu Studio 15.10 fresh install, Asus K55A, no love).

Answer (score 0):

matthewwittering.com is down, so I can't see what you tried there. Have you tried the official support instructions?:

http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom

Comment: Thank you for your help Aaron.
I've just added extra details to my original post showing the error I get when compiling the driver by following the official support instructions.

Comment: You shouldn't need the w8001 driver for your device. Try just: sudo modprobe -r wacom;
sudo modprobe wacom